# Why can't I apply texture paint to my object in blender 2.8?

Tags: texture-painting

I can apply paint to a cube, but not to my complicated object, even though I defined the material and I linked the image texture to the principal in the shader. It seems I cannot select anything in the UV map, so that might be the problem. (apologies but for some reason I cannot comment on my own question...)

[image]

Comment: Did you unwrap the mesh and set up a texture paint slot?

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you for your comment, as seen in the screenshot, I defined the texture paint material and the UV map is there too. Is that what your comment was referring to please?

Comment: I see you have an UV mapping for your mesh - but your image texture node needs to be plugged into the Diffuse/Albedo channel of your Principled BSDF for it to show up in the 3d view. Remove the connection to the RGB node until you decide how to use that in conjunction with the image texture using a Color Mix Node later on. I saw the comments about Vertex Paint, and that means you will need to plug the Attribute Node 'Col' into the Diffuse slot to preview in your shader.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to connect the image texture node to your shading node instead the rgb one.

Comment: thank you Alejandro I am going to try that but actually I found a solution. I could paint my object without any problem with Vertex Paint.

Comment: Well, i've painted objects with way more tris, i don't think your object is too complicated for texture paint, it may be some settings stuff, i can check out your file if you want to!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I could paint my object without any problem with Vertex Paint by selecting the vertices. May this sculpted object is too complicated for Texture Painting?

Comment: no it's not too complicated for texture painting, as someone says you need to plug the Image Texture node into the Diffuse one (or Principled). Vertex Paint is a completely different tool, the painting will completely depend on your topology, but if you're glad with the result...

Comment: thank you moonboots, i connected the image texture node but I still cannot paint. according to other answers it seems that i have to select UV map sections, but for some reason i cannot....

Comment: please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend) and share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thank you for your comment again. I couldnot upload the file (probably too heavy) so I updated the screen shot. If you have time, thank you for taking a look. If not , no worries!

Comment: I don't see any screenshot, please use another platform if it's too heavy for this one. Also, don't use the Your Answer field to make comment, Your Answer is made for users to propose you answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you only connected an "RGB Node" to the "Principled BSDF color slot.
You can't paint on a "RGB Node".
For that you need a texture which you seem to have created above, but not yet linked. Connect that lonely "Image Texture" Node above to the color slot, replacing the connection of the "RGB Node".
In your lower uv view the texture seems to be already selected, since it only shows the start of the name, be sure to select the texture itself, as the image and save the image before you start painting.
Then, once you assign the Image Texture to the color slot it should make your object change the color to the dark gray shown behind the uv unwrapped mesh. From there all should work then, happy painting.
And Blender can handle more then that, the more the slower based on the machine, but it's not the reason why it's not working.